# Selective XML reading

Tags: java

I am able to read XML as per the code below.

This is a sample input file:

```xml
<explain>
    <Query-Text>
    </Query-Text>
    <Plan>
        <Node-Type></Node-Type>
        <Startup-Cost></Startup-Cost>
        <Total-Cost></Total-Cost>
        <Actual-Total-Time></Actual-Total-Time>
        <Actual-Rows></Actual-Rows>
        <Actual-Loops></Actual-Loops>
        <Plans>
                <Plan>
                        <Node-Type></Node-Type>
                        <Startup-Cost></Startup-Cost>
                        <Total-Cost></Total-Cost>
                        <Actual-Rows></Actual-Rows>
                        <Actual-Loops></Actual-Loops>
                </Plan>
          </Plans>
    </Plan>
</explain>
```

I just need to read in tag `PLAN: "Total-Cost"` and `"Actual-Total-Time"` information from the first `PLAN` tag.The problem is that there is `PLAN` in an inner hierarchy and this is being read as well. How could I do to read only the first `PLAN` tag, not the ones inside that do not interest me?
This is my code:

```
File fXmlFile = new File("/home/user1/Downloads/LOGT1.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Plan");

for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
    //SAMPLE Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
    System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());                            
    if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {             Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
        System.out.println("Total Cost query: " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("Total-Cost").item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("Actual Total Time query:" + eElement.getElementsByTagName("Actual-Total-Time").item(0).getTextContent());
        }
```

This code doesn't raise any errors, but it does not follow the desired behavior.

Comment: Yes this code is identical to that of this link: http://www.guj.com.br/t/melhor-forma-de-ler-xml/90593/6

It is not working the way I need it .. I need to be shown only the information of the first PLAN tag, and it is not doing it.
Do you have any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) { //SAMPLE       
    Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
    if (nNode.getParent().getNodeName().equals("Plans")) {
        continue;
    }
    System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use **XPath** to get the values. Below code will give you what you want:

```
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

String Total_Cost = xPath.evaluate("//explain/Plan/Total-Cost/text()", doc).trim();
String Actual_Total_Time = xPath.evaluate("//explain/Plan/Actual-Total-Time/text()", doc).trim();
```